# n-dimensional wave equation proving the compactness of the support of the solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

The question is the following. Let $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,+\infty))$ be a solution of the problem

\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-\Delta u = 0\\
u(x,0) = \phi(x)\\
u_t(x,0)=\psi(x)
\end{cases}
where the initial data $\phi$ and $\psi$ have compact support (i.e. vanish identically outside a closed ball $\overline{B(0,R)}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$). Prove that for every $t\geq0$, $u(x,t)$ vanish identically outside the closed ball $\overline{B(0,R+t)}$.

Probably it is a direct consequence of the finite propagation speed but I can't formalize it...

Comment: What do you mean by _finite propagation speed_ exactly?

Comment: The statement which says that if the initial data are zero on $\overline{B(x^o,t^o)}\times\{t=0\}$, then $u$ is zero at all points of the cone $K(x^o,t^o)$ (i.e. the values of the initial data outside the ball $\overline{B(x^o,t^o)}$ do not affect the value of u in the cone $K(x^o,t^o)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a point $(x_0,t_0)$ with $|x_0|>R+t_0$. The initial values vanish on the ball $B(x_0,|x_0|-R)$. By finite speed of propagation, the solution vanishes on the cone $K$ built on top of this ball such that the $t$-time section of this cone is $B(x_0,|x_0|-R-t)\times \{t\}$ for $t<|x_0|-R$.

In particular, the $t_0$ section of $K$ is $B(x_0,|x_0|-R-t_0)\times \{t_0\}$ which contains the point $(x_0,t_0)$. This implies the claim.